# Результат выражения при постфиксном инкременте

Tags: java

Почему значение переменной `с` будет равно `8`?

```
int b = 5;
int a = 12;
int c = ++a - b++;
System.out.println(c);
int d = b++ * 2;
System.out.println(d);
```

Ведь если мы добавляем к значению переменной `a` единицу, то у нас получается `13`, после чего отнимаем `b = 5`, затем увеличиваем на единицу, то есть в итоге получится `9`.

В чем я не прав?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте про префиксный и постфиксный инкремент.

Answer (score 2):

При использовании операции постинкремента значение переменной сначала используется в выражении, а потом увеличивается на 1.
Поэтому значение переменной `b` увеличится только после того, как "отдаст" свое значение в выражение, в котором участвует.

Т.е. по факту происходит так:

```
int c = ++a - b; // b отдало значение в выражение
b = b + 1;       // и увеличилось
```

Вот если бы было чуть посложнее, например

```
int b = 5;
int a = 12;
int c = ++a - b++ + b;
System.out.println(c);
```

то ответом было бы 14, т.к. выражение `++a - b` дало результат 8, затем, как раз-таки `b` увеличилось на 1 и стало равным 6, и результатом сложения  получилось бы 14 (8 + 6).

Answer (score 0):

`++x` и `x++` имееют разные возращаемые значения. `++x` увеличивает переменную `x` на 1, и возвращает это новое значение, а `x++` сначала вернет занчение `x` и только потом увеличит значение переменной.

Ваш код отработает следующим образом:

```
c = ++a - b++
     13 - b++  // a увеличилось на 1 и вернуло значение 13
     13 - 5    // b++ сначало вернуло значение b, а затем увеличило значение b на 1
     8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int b = 5;
int a = 12;
int c = ++a - b++;
System.out.println(c);
int d = b++ * 2;
System.out.println(d);
```

Компилятор приведет к следующему виду, без сокращенных записей:

```
int b = 5;
int a = 12;
a = a + 1;
int tmp1 = a;
int tmp2 = b;
b = b + 1;
int c = tmp1 - tmp2;
System.out.println(c);
int tmp3 = b;
b = b + 1;
int d = tmp3 * 2;
System.out.println(d);
```

Как то так.

Comment: @Regent, я же не jvm байт-код привожу, а просто разбиваю сокращенную форму для понятности.

Comment: @Regent, так то оно так... но иногда многословность дает больше понятности. Я раскрыл постфиксную форму через доп переменную и префиксную через доп переменную. Как по мне, то так понятней принцип.

Comment: Хорошо. Некоторый смысл в плане понятности в ней действительно есть.